# AngularJS Service not waiting for other service to complete

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-http

I've got an issue when a service is calling a service.  It seems that things are executing out of order.

```
.service('addressService', function($http) {
    var addressService = this;
    addressService.getLatitudeLongitude = function(address) {
        console.log('in addressService.getLatitudeLongitude')
        $http.get('/location?address=' + encodeURIComponent(address))
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('success')
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers,config) {
            console.log('error')
        });
    };
})

.service('weatherService', function($http, addressService){
    var weatherService = this;

    weatherService.getWeather = function(latitude, longitude) {
        console.log('get weather')
        $http.get('/all_weather?latitude=' + latitude + '&longitude=' + longitude)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        return data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            return null;
        });
    };

    weatherService.getCurrentWeather = function(address) {
        var lat_lon = addressService.getLatitudeLongitude(address) 
        console.log(lat_lon)
        return weatherService.getWeather(lat_lon.lat, lat_lon.lng).currently;
    };
})
```

The output is:

```js
weather.js:25 getCurrentWeatherByAddress 
weather.js:99 in addressService.getLatitudeLongitude
weather.js:129 undefined
angular.js:11655 TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
    at weatherService.getCurrentWeather (weather.js:130)
    at weather.getCurrentWeatherByAddress (weather.js:28)
    at ib.functionCall (angular.js:12404)
    at hint.js:798
    at n.$get.n.$eval (angular.js:14466)
    at n.$get.n.$apply (angular.js:14565)
    at n.scopePrototype.$apply (hint.js:1478)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (hint.js:797)
    at HTMLButtonElement.c (angular.js:3032)
weather.js:102 success
weather.js:103 Object {lat: 44.8735964, lng: -93.2835137}
```

It appears that `weatherService.getCurrentWeather(address)` is trying to continue past `addressService.getLatitudeLongitude(address)` before `addressService.getLatitudeLongitude(address)` is finished making the request.  After `weatherService.getCurrentweather` errors out, the rest of the logs from `addressService.getLatitudeLongitude` are outputted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the functions to complete using the returned promises (and return the promises). You are treating async code as sync code right now

```
.service('addressService', function($http) {
    var addressService = this;
    addressService.getLatitudeLongitude = function(address) {
        console.log('in addressService.getLatitudeLongitude')

        //RETURN THIS PROMISE
        return $http.get('/location?address=' + encodeURIComponent(address))
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('success')
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers,config) {
            console.log('error')
        });
    };
})

.service('weatherService', function($http, addressService){
    var weatherService = this;

    weatherService.getWeather = function(latitude, longitude) {
        console.log('get weather')
        $http.get('/all_weather?latitude=' + latitude + '&longitude=' + longitude)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        return data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            return null;
        });
    };

    weatherService.getCurrentWeather = function(address) {
        var lat_lon;

        //WAIT FOR THAT PROMISE TO RESOLVE
        return addressService.getLatitudeLongitude(address).then(function(result){
            lat_lon = result;
            return weatherService.getWeather(lat_lon.lat, lat_lon.lng).currently;
            console.log(lat_lon)
        });

    };
})
```